# Detect websocket connection break on internet connection loss stomp client java

Tags: java, spring-boot, websocket, spring-websocket, stomp

Java stomp client does not respond on internet connection loss. Is there any way to get an exception inside handleTransportError method on internet connection loss or socket disconnection?

```
public class SocketHandler extends StompSessionHandlerAdapter{

@Override
public void handleTransportError(){
 //Expected error here
}

@Override
public void handleException(){

}

@Override
public void afterConnected(){

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The TCP protocol can be slow to notice a connection loss.  That is why the STOMP 1.1 protcol introduced the Heart-beat feature.  Heart-beating can optionally be used to test the healthiness of the underlying TCP connection and to make sure that the remote end is alive and kicking.

Depending on what is negotiated with heart-beating at initial connection time, the client or server may be required to send periodic "heart beat" messages.  If your client doesn't receive a heart-beat from the server within the prescribed time period it assumes that the connection is lost.

Comment: Could you provide some example code if you don't mind?

Comment: Please, have you done a search on "spring websocket stomp heartbeat"?

Answer (score 0):

Yes there is, these methods allow you to access the Session and Exception objects but you have wrong method signatures.

https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/messaging/simp/stomp/StompSessionHandlerAdapter.html

Comment: I forgot to add parameters to the above code. But I am using the methods that you specified and I do not get any exception objects if I lose internet connection while I'm connected to a spring boot socket server. I get exception only if the server is unreachable or if the server is down.